# PHP doesn't recognize fields dynamically added with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL database of orders that each have various activities associated with them. My PHP/HTML page pulls down the activities when you click an order and allows the user to change attributes of the activities with a form. On submit another PHP file loops through activities in the table and runs an update query on the database. Works great!

I have recently added a JavaScript function that will add activities to the list (appendChild, createElement...). I then added to my PHP file an `INSERT` query for the new activities.

The problem is that when I run the update PHP file it is not looping through the newly added records that were added with JavaScript. I checked it by using `<?php print $size = count($_POST['FcastID']) ?>` and the value doesn't change when records have been added.

The records look fine when added to the table and the id and name convention match the other records. It seems like the page needs to be refreshed before the PHP file runs.

**PHP file with dynamically created html form**

```
<div id="submit"><form method="post" action="Up_Forecast.php"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
....
<table id="fcast">
<?
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_fcast))
{
echo "<tr id='fcastRow[$i]'>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyJan[$i]' name='qtyJan[$i]' value='".$row[Jan]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyFeb[$i]' name='qtyFeb[$i]' value='".$row[Feb]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyMar[$i]' name='qtyMar[$i]' value='".$row[Mar]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyApr[$i]' name='qtyApr[$i]' value='".$row[Apr]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyMay[$i]' name='qtyMay[$i]' value='".$row[May]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyJun[$i]' name='qtyJun[$i]' value='".$row[Jun]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyJul[$i]' name='qtyJul[$i]' value='".$row[Jul]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyAug[$i]' name='qtyAug[$i]' value='".$row[Aug]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtySep[$i]' name='qtySep[$i]' value='".$row[Sep]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyOct[$i]' name='qtyOct[$i]' value='".$row[Oct]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyNov[$i]' name='qtyNov[$i]' value='".$row[Nov]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='qtyDec[$i]' name='qtyDec[$i]' value='".$row[Dec]."'/></td>";
echo "<td class='medium'><input type='text' id='Totalqty[$i]' name='Totalqty[$i]' value='".$row[Total]."' disabled/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
++$i;
}
?>
<tr><td class="blank"></td><td class="mini"><input type="button" onclick="addRowYear(this)" value="Add"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

**Javascript function to add row**

```
function addRowYear(lastRow){
    var rowNo = lastRow.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var newRow = document.getElementById("fcast").insertRow(rowNo);

    newRow.setAttribute("id","fcastRow["+rowNo+"]");

    var cell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell0.setAttribute("class","mini");
var input0 = document.createElement("input");
    input0.setAttribute("type","text");
    input0.setAttribute("name","FcastID["+rowNo+"]");
    input0.setAttribute("value","new");
    cell0.appendChild(input0);

var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell1.setAttribute("class","mini");
var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.setAttribute("type","text");
    input1.setAttribute("name","Fcast_ActID["+rowNo+"]");
    input1.setAttribute("id","Fcast_ActID["+rowNo+"]");
    cell1.appendChild(input1);
var curAct = document.getElementById("selAct").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("Fcast_ActID["+rowNo+"]").value = curAct;

var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    cell2.setAttribute("class","mini");
var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.setAttribute("type","text");
    input2.setAttribute("name","Year["+rowNo+"]");
    cell2.appendChild(input2);

var month = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
//alert(month[i]);
    x=3;
var cell = newRow.insertCell(x);
    cell.setAttribute("class","medium");
var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type","text");
    input.setAttribute("class","numbers");
    input.setAttribute("name","qty"+month[i]+"["+rowNo+"]");
    input.setAttribute("id","qty"+month[i]+"["+rowNo+"]");
    input.setAttribute("onkeyup","findTotal()");
    cell.appendChild(input);
    x=x+1;
    }

var cell15 = newRow.insertCell(15);
    cell15.setAttribute("class","medium");
var input15 = document.createElement("input");
    input15.setAttribute("type","text");
    input15.setAttribute("class","numbers");
    input15.setAttribute("name","Totalqty["+rowNo+"]");
    input15.setAttribute("id","Totalqty["+rowNo+"]");
    cell15.appendChild(input15);
```

**PHP Update - Called on Submit of form**

```
$size = count($_POST['FcastID']);
$i = 0
while ($i < $size) {
    $FcastID = $_POST['FcastID'][$i];
    $ActID = $_POST['Fcast_ActID'][$i];
    $Year = $_POST['Year'][$i];
    $Jan = $_POST['qtyJan'][$i];
    $Feb = $_POST['qtyFeb'][$i];
    $Mar = $_POST['qtyMar'][$i];
    $Apr = $_POST['qtyApr'][$i];
    $May = $_POST['qtyMay'][$i];
    $Jun = $_POST['qtyJun'][$i];
    $Jul = $_POST['qtyJul'][$i];
    $Aug = $_POST['qtyAug'][$i];
    $Sep = $_POST['qtySep'][$i];
    $Oct = $_POST['qtyOct'][$i];
    $Nov = $_POST['qtyNov'][$i];
    $Dec = $_POST['qtyDec'][$i];
    $Total = $_POST['Totalqty'][$i];
    $update = "UPDATE FCAST SET
    Year='$Year',
    Jan=replace('$Jan',',',''),
    Feb=replace('$Feb',',',''),
    Mar=replace('$Mar',',',''),
    Apr=replace('$Apr',',',''),
    May=replace('$May',',',''),
    Jun=replace('$Jun',',',''),
    Jul=replace('$Jul',',',''),
    Aug=replace('$Aug',',',''),
    Sep=replace('$Sep',',',''),
    Oct=replace('$Oct',',',''),
    Nov=replace('$Nov',',',''),
    `Dec`=replace('$Dec',',',''),
    Total=replace('$Total',',','')
    WHERE
    FcastID='$FcastID'";
    mysqli_query($link, $update);
```

Comment: So, if you read other questions - you know that we definitely will ask for a code.

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: Welcome on SO. It's better if you could provide some code to help others understand your problem. You'll increase your chances to get usefule answers.

Comment: In which way do you call your PHP page from javascript? Via AJAX?

Comment: -1 for not posting code.

Comment: @Ayushman: This is a new user, give him at least some minutes to improve the question

Comment: Print your `$_POST` variable in the action url file. Maybe it will give you a clue. And +1 for new user, even though the code is missing.

Comment: Note that `$update` contains several SQL injection opportunities - use parameterisation to avoid this with user input here.

Comment: Also try to inspect your dinamically created form with `Inspect Element` from [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/firebug/) on Firefox. It might give you a clue.

Comment: @machineaddict: I downloaded Firebug and used inspect element and the element looks good as far as names and ids and consistency with other rows. When I count the rows using javascript it recognizes the added records but still when the php runs it doesn't see the added records.

Comment: I got it to work last night with all my same code but by moving the `</form>` tag to the last tag before the `</body>` tag. I'm not sure why it fixed it because the `</form>` tag was always after the table. @Birrel I appreciate your detailed answer and have accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say.  Something I have used in the past that works well is the following:

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //... $key is name of field, $value is the value
}
```

This goes through each individual field in the submitted form and reads the value in each.  I've used this exact script for dynamically-created forms, and it works great.  You have to be careful, though, if you use the same name for different fields, the values will be stored as arrays.

**EDIT**

*HTML:*

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<div>
  <div>
    <p>
    <label class="reg_label" for="field_name">Item:</label>
    <input class="text_area" name="field_name[]" type="text" id="testing" tabindex="98" style="width: 150px;"/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" class="someClass1"/>
<input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" class="someClass2" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var j = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.someClass1').click(function (e) {

        var num = $(this).prev().children().length; 
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); 

        var newElem = $(this).prev().children(':last').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

        if(newElem.children().children().last().hasClass('otherOption')){
            newElem.children().children().last().remove();
        }

        newElem.children().children().each(function(){
            var curName = $(this).attr('name');
            var newName = '';
            $(this).attr('id', 'name' + num + '_' + j);
            j++;
        });

        newElem.children().children().each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('value');
        });

        $(this).prev().children(':last').after(newElem);

        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('.someClass2').click(function (e) {
        var num = $(this).prev().prev().children().length; 

        $(this).prev().prev().children(':last').remove(); 
        if (num - 1 == 1) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }); 
});
```

It isn't all that important to know how the JavaScript code works.  All you need to know is that clicking on the "Add" button will duplicate the field and clicking on "Remove" will remove the most recently added field.  Try it out at the link provided.

*PHP:*

This is where the magic happens…

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST as $name => $item){
        if($name != 'submit'){
            for($m=0; $m < sizeof($item); $m++){
                echo ($name.' '.$item[$m].'<br>');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Looks easy enough, right?

This PHP code is within the same file as the form, so first we check to see if the form has been submitted by checking for the name of the submit button `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){…}`.

If the form has been submitted, go through each submitted item `foreach($_POST as $name => $item){…}`.

The submit button counts as one of the fields submitted, but we aren't interested in storing that value, so check to make sure the value you are reading in is not from the submit button `if($name != 'submit'){…}`.

Finally, all the fields within this form have the same name `field_name[]`.  The square brackets are used for multiple items that share the same name.  They are then stored in an array.  Read through each item within that array for the length of the array `for($m=0; $m < sizeof($item); $m++){…}` and then do what you'd like with each value.  In this case, I've just printed them to the screen `echo ($name.' '.$item[$m].'<br>');`

Below are a couple screen-shots of the page…

Before submitting the form:

[image: Before]

After submitting the form:

[image: After]

You can go to the page and view the code (right click -> View Source), but the PHP will not show up in the source.  I assure you that all the PHP used for this is shown above - just the few lines.

If each item has a completely unique name (which you can achieve via JavaScript when adding fields), then you will not need to loop through the array of values (i.e. will not need `for($m=0; $m < sizeof($item); $m++){…}` block).  Instead, you'll likely read the value using simply `$item`.  If you name your fields with the square brackets (i.e. `field_name[]`), but only have one of that field, then reading a singular value may require `$item` or `$item[0]`.  In that case you'll just have to test it and see.  Some field types behave differently than others (i.e. input, text area, radio buttons, etc).

**The Whole Thing**

Here is the entire code for index.php - you can just copy and paste it and run it on your own server.  Just make sure to change the name of the file in the `action` attribute `<form>` tag…

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST as $name => $item){
        if($name != 'submit'){
            for($m=0; $m < sizeof($item); $m++){
                echo ($name.' '.$item[$m].'<br>');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<div>
  <div>
    <p>
    <label class="reg_label" for="field_name">Item:</label>
    <input class="text_area" name="field_name[]" type="text" id="testing" tabindex="98" style="width: 150px;"/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" class="someClass1"/>
<input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" class="someClass2" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>

<script>
var j = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.someClass1').click(function (e) {

        var num = $(this).prev().children().length; 
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); 

        var newElem = $(this).prev().children(':last').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

        if(newElem.children().children().last().hasClass('otherOption')){
            newElem.children().children().last().remove();
        }

        newElem.children().children().each(function(){
            var curName = $(this).attr('name');
            var newName = '';
            $(this).attr('id', 'name' + num + '_' + j);
            j++;
        });

        newElem.children().children().each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('value');
        });

        $(this).prev().children(':last').after(newElem);

        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('.someClass2').click(function (e) {
        var num = $(this).prev().prev().children().length; 

        $(this).prev().prev().children(':last').remove(); 
        if (num - 1 == 1) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }); 
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to give this a try but I am having trouble applying it to my situation. I have posted the code since you answered, you think you could give me some pointers.

Comment: @Brian.k just edited my answer for you.  Please read through and try it out.  Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.  If solution works, please accept and/or upvote.

Comment: I did not use your HTML code, nor your JavaScript code.  *HOW* you make the form and the fields does not matter, so long as you a) create fields with truly unique names, or b) create fields with the same name using `[]`.  Reading through afterwards is the same as the PHP code provided.  Modify as needed to suit your solution.

Comment: I got it to work last night with all my same code but by moving the `</form>` tag to the last tag before the `</body>` tag. I'm not sure why it fixed it because the `</form>` tag was always after the table. @Birrel I appreciate your detailed answer and have accepted it.